# How to communicate domain-specific errors from API to be parsed by client code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating an API using ASP.Net Core. The API is not public; it's intended to be used solely by a particular B2B/B2E mobile app we're developing.

I need to tell the mobile app exactly what kind of error occurred, so that it can display helpful error messages. The status code itself is not sufficient for this, since the same status code can cover several different domain-specific errors that should be differentiated in the app. Thus, the only way to do this seems to be sending magical strings, preferably defined in a shared project referenced by both the API and mobile app projects. So far, so good.

I first used ASP.NET Web API 2 (not Core), and there my controllers returned `IHttpActionResult` and I could simply `return this.ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = myStatusCode, ReasonPhrase = myReasonPhrase })` (I delegated this creation to a simple helper method on the controller, so the actions were very clean and short). However, `ResponseMessageResult` does not seem to be defined in ASP.Net Core.

I have no former experience with ASP.Net Core and can't seem to find the answer to my use case anywhere, so I'm wondering how to best go about this. A few possible solutions that come to mind:

- Create error responses in the controller with a specific reason phrase. This is what I was doing before, and it seems fairly clean and simple.
- Throw exceptions in the controller (or, preferably, from the controller's dependencies) and use an exception filter to transform that to error responses with specific reason phrases. Not sure I like this, since it might require me to define as many custom exceptions as reason codes I want to return.
- For any of the above, instead of placing the string in the reason phrase, place it in an object in the response body. Seems heavy-handed seeing as a magical string in the reason phrase suffices for my purposes. Though I could perhaps add an `Error` property to my normal API response for each controller and simply return an `ObjectResult` in all cases.

I have no idea which of these, or perhaps another solution entirely, might be a sensible way to convey domain-specific errors from an ASP.Net Core API.

**How can I cleanly and robustly communicate domain-specific errors via an ASP.Net Core REST API to be parsed by client code?**

Answer (score 1):

How I do it:

```
public class SerializableMessage {
    public SerializableMessage(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller

```
try
{
    // something that throws
} catch (ExpectedException e)
{
    return BadRequest(new SerializableMessage("You messed up");
}
```

Then when client receives a non 2xx reponse it reads out (e.g. if content type is json) `response.message`.

The way I see it is the client knows what is meant to happen, so all it needs do is fail or potentially display a message as to what went wrong, as most errors are irrecoverable by user intervention.

As for modelstate errors I serialize these as an `Errors` property in a `SerializableErrorMessage` class in a similar way to how asp.net core does it already. This gives the option of specifying an additional message error string. As for uncaught exceptions, I just let a global filter send a 500 response and log the exception using something (application insights).

Have a look at the methods available on the Controller class. Intellisense (can't remember the actual name) documentation is pretty good with asp.net core libraries. May give you inspiration!!

The bottom line is, have a serializable class that contains properties you think would be useful. Don't rely on magic dynamic objects and I would avoid contextual properties (e.g. endpoint1 returns Error endpoint2 returns ErrorMessage and Error) maintenance nightmare in remembering what properties are expected!

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Comment regarding “*I would avoid contextual properties (e.g. endpoint1 returns Error endpoint2 returns ErrorMessage and Error) maintenance nightmare in remembering what properties are expected!*” – if this is an argument against having an Error property in the response objects, I'm not sure I agree. The response objects would be shared between the API and the client, so everything would be strongly typed.

Comment: Oh no, I mean have a defined Error object that has known properties. Instead of just having, say, one return a string and one return a list of errors! Have both return a common object that has an Errors property with a list of errors, for example :) This is just how I have decided to do it, you may come up with something that makes much more sense to you and your team, and that works better.

Comment: So, in your opinion, would it be okay to have an `Error` property (e.g. an enum) on each response object? For example, `SignInError Error` on a `SignInResponse`, `GetTodoError Error` on a `GetTodoResponse`, etc. Then, I could just deserialize the response without being dependent on the actual status code, which could simplify the client code a bit.

Comment: A descriminator so you know what type of object wouldn't be a bad idea, no! More complex than what we need for our system. However this definitely makes error handling easier if you need to do something wth the data returned from an error